# Linq extract segment from delimited text column

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a database column, delimited by colons, describing a category hierarchy like so:

ID   | Category

100  | Domestic:Trees:Fruit:Apples

I would like to extract only the third segment of the hierarchy "Fruit" from the text. How can I use Linq Regex or Linq Filtering to extract just that segment? Is it a good idea to extract information this way for every time a user selects a category?

Comment: Is normalizing the database an option?

Comment: Yes its possible to split the data into its own category columns like cat1, cat2, cat3. Would that be the standard way of doing things? I tested the Linq query provided by Scott Lvey below and it takes around 7 seconds. I'm sure splitting the string on every click can't be the way most site does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes it sound like you want a linq answer only - so if you wanted to use linq, you could do this...

```
string s = "Domestic:Trees:Fruit:Apples".Split(':')
           .Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
           .Where(i => i.index == 2)
           .Select(i => i.item);
```

Doing it in linq vs just splitting the string and taking the one you need isn't going to make your code any easier to read - so you may want to just consider going with just a straight split as Andrew suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`String.Split(Char[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method:

> Returns a string array that contains
>   the substrings in this instance that
>   are delimited by elements of a
>   specified Unicode character array.

Basically you can split the original string up based on a delimiter that you specify.  This method returns a `String[]`.  Here is a small example of how to use it:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String s = "Domestic:Trees:Fruit:Apples";
        String[] parts = s.Split(':');
        Console.WriteLine(parts[2]);
    }
}
```